# Spring Controller not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring and creating simple two page web app that will go to specified link from index page. here is my `web.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>indexFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>filter.indexFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>indexFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/index.htm</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>listener.listenerDB</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here is the index.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Welcome to Spring Web MVC project</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="home.htm" method="get">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Code for dispatcher-servlet is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>


    <!--
    Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
    for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
    define an explicit mapping for it.
    -->

    <bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
                <prop key="login.htm">loginController</prop>
                <prop key="home.htm">homeController</prop> 
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
          p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
          p:suffix=".jsp" />

    <!--
    The index controller.
    -->
    <bean name="indexController"
          class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
          p:viewName="index" />


    <bean name="loginController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController" p:viewName="login" />
    <bean name="homeController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController" p:viewName="home" />
</beans>
```

My controller class is myController.java that looks like:

```
package controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.jboss.weld.logging.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author rajkumar
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class homeController {

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public void homeManage(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)  throws SQLException, ServletException, IOException{
        System.out.println("Raj");            
    }
}
```

Finally home.jsp is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     Hiii
    <f:forEach var="element" items="${deptInfo}" varStatus="i">
        <c:out value="${element['dept_id']}" />
    </f:forEach>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this web app as per my knowledge it should print "Raj" to the console but it doesn't print it. I have also tried to debug the app but still it is not going to the controller class.

Is there any mistake for mapping controller?

Comment: I think your controller method needs to at least return a string which would be the name of the next view. The viewresolver needs this. When setting the log level to debug for org.springframework you should see a line that confirms the mapping of the request path to the controller.

Comment: Both things are proper, we can define it in class level and all the request with GET method will go to homeManage(). So i think it is not the issue

Comment: @mwhs i have this line in dispatcher-servlet:                       <bean name="homeController" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController" p:viewName="home" /> So it will resolve view , there is no problem with view the problem is it can't get controller

Comment: Since you're using an annotated controller (RESTful controller), registering beans in `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is not required. Unregister those beans from the `dispatcher-servlet.xml` file and return a string representing a view that you wish to display on the `GET` request from your method in your controller, `homeManage()`.

Comment: What url are you trying to access? Activate the logs and see if your requestmapping is actually being registered om startup.

Comment: add <annotation-driven /> in your dispatcher-servlet file as you are using annotations

Comment: @OomphFortuity i have <mvc:annotation-driven/> already in my dispatcher-servlet.

Comment: @user3264957 your controller needs to return some information to the viewresolver. AFAIK Spring will not map a request to a void method. Either make the controller method return a String or a ModelAndView object.

Answer (score 0):

change your controller to:

*all other imports

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
@Controller
public class homeController {
@RequestMapping("/home")
public ModelAndView homeManage(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)  throws     SQLException, ServletException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Raj");    
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

}